# Absorbing bounded quantifiers, formal proof?

Tags: logic, arithmetic

Intuitively I get in arithmetic aka the natural numbers that:

$\exists n\,\exists m\,(m < n \wedge P(m)) \Leftrightarrow \exists k\,P(k)$

But I am having problems finding a formal proof.

What I tried so far, is using $P(j) \Leftrightarrow \neg Q(j)$, and then this is the same as $\forall n\,\forall m (m < n \Rightarrow Q(m)) \Leftrightarrow \forall k\,Q(k)$. The $\Leftarrow$ direction looks like specialization, weakening and generalization. The $\Rightarrow$ direction could work with changing the quantifier order and then using a specialization.

Comment: What kind of formal proof are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof which I just verified in Agda so is pretty much as formal as they come:

The forward direction is trivial: take $k = m$.

The backward direction: take $m = k$ and $n = k+1$.

That's really all there is to it.

Preamble to set up the appropriate definitions of equality, $+$, $<$ and so on:

```
open import Agda.Primitive using (Level; lzero; lsuc; _⊔_)

infix 5 _≡_
data _≡_ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A → Set a where
    refl : x ≡ x

data Sg {n : _} {m : _} (A : Set m) (B : A → Set n) : Set (m ⊔ n) where
  _,_ : (a : A) → (b : B a) → Sg A B

infix 15 _&&_
record _&&_ {a b} (A : Set a) (B : Set b) : Set (a ⊔ b) where
  constructor _,,_
  field
    fst : A
    snd : B

data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  succ : ℕ → ℕ

infix 15 _+N_
infix 100 succ
_+N_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
zero +N y = y
succ x +N y = succ (x +N y)

infix 5 _<N_
record _<N_ (a : ℕ) (b : ℕ) : Set where
    constructor le
    field
      x : ℕ
      proof : (succ x) +N a ≡ b
```

The actual proof:

```
lemm : (P : ℕ → Set) → Sg ℕ (λ i → Sg ℕ (λ j → (j <N i) && P j)) → Sg ℕ (λ k → P k)
lemm P (n , (m , (fst ,, snd))) = m , snd

lemm' : (P : ℕ → Set) → Sg ℕ (λ k → P k) → Sg ℕ (λ i → Sg ℕ (λ j → (j <N i) && P j))
lemm' P (k , b) = (succ k , (k , record { fst = le zero refl ; snd = b }))
```

Comment: Does Agda have a function to show the proof, and not only the proof object?

Comment: In theory I could execute that code, indeed. In fact I've never actually executed any Agda code; only used the type checker.

Comment: But the proof is really "The code type-checked, so we have demonstrated a valid realisation in the BHK interpretation of logic; the proposition must therefore be consistent because it has a model".

Comment: May I deposit some doubts, for a proof we would like to have a generally valid propositon, not a satisfiable proposition, this is also what type inhabitation verifies. In Agda you even give the proof object and the type, so it has much less to do than Coq or HOL/Isabelle. But isn't Agda intelligent enough, in this show case, to have some implicit mechanism so that N needs not to be specified for each occurence of Sg?

Comment: For example in (P : ℕ → Set) → Sg ℕ (λ k → P k), it should know that k is from N, and therefor Sg is also (N->Set)->Set. But (m ⊔ n) could make it more complicated. Just curious, what version of Agda did you use?

Comment: I upvoted, but will still wait a little.

Comment: This is Agda 2.5.4.1. You can certainly get rid of the universe polymorphism to simplify things; would you prefer me to edit the answer to remove it?

Comment: No its ok. Its nice example of many things explicit. But you wrote "The forward direction is trivial: take k=m", I am currently manually verifying something. Isn't it "n=anything", "m=k"? Respectively the variable names is anyway irrrelevant since everything is lamda and then conjunction elimination is used. Got, it.

Comment: @j4nbur53 The forward direction only requires us to demonstrate a $k$ such that $P(k)$, given $m$ and $n$ such that $m<n$ and $P(m)$. It only asks for one variable to be filled. At this point, we already have $n$ and $m$, and don't need to find them.

Comment: This book shows derivation trees from Agda: https://plfa.github.io/Lambda/#derivation , how were they done? Manually I guess, since it says "informal".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried a translation, of the Agda proof, to natural deduction.
From arithmetic I only assume k < k+1, there are different ways to
define "<", I didn't replicate the arithmetic part:

Here is a [natural deduction](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systeme_nat%C3%BCrlichen_Schlie%C3%9Fens#Pr%C3%A4dikatenlogik) proof.

<= Direction:

```
                       ----------         ------------
                       |- k < k+1         P(k) |- P(k)       
                       -------------------------------
                           P(k) |- k < k+1 /\ P(k)
                         ---------------------------
                         P(k) |- ∃m(m < k+1 /\ P(m))
  ------------------     -----------------------------
  ∃k P(k) |- ∃k P(k)     P(k) |- ∃n ∃m(m < n /\ P(m))
  ----------------------------------------------------
           ∃k P(k) |- ∃n ∃m(m < n /\ P(m))
```

=> Direction:

```
                                        ------------------------------
                                        m < n /\ P(m) |- m < n /\ P(m)
                                        ------------------------------
                                              m < n /\ P(m) |- P(m)
 -------------------------------------------  -------------------------
 ∃n∃m(m < n /\ P(m)) |- ∃n∃m(m < n /\ P(m))  m < n /\ P(m) |- ∃k P(k) 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                      ∃n∃m(m < n /\ P(m)) |- ∃k P(k)
```